# Honda Unicorn skids every time I use the rear brakes only

Tags: honda, motorcycle, brakes, unicorn

Honda Unicorn 160cc motorcycle skids every time I quickly hit the rear brakes. Even at slow speeds such as 10kph (about 6mph)

Is there a problem with my riding style or could it be the bike?

I have only driven it for 10000km.

Answer (score 5):

70% or more of your braking power is at the front brakes, so this is probably normal.  When you brake on a motorcycle (or car, or anything), weight shifts to the front, and this naturally unloads the rear wheel to some degree.  Less weight on the wheel means less traction.

Rear brakes should only be relied on when slowing down normally.  If you really need to stop quickly, plan on the front brakes doing almost all of the work.

That said, your rear brakes *could* need adjustment, and could be locking up a little too easily, but that boundary between riding "style" (skill) and a mechanical problem is probably best determined by a mechanic or at least someone that's ridden your type of bike for a long time.

Comment: I thought applying Front (disc) brakes is dangerous at higher speeds when you want to stop the bike quickly. I once did Front braking when I was driving about a little less than 40 kmph on a road full of potholes thinking disc brakes are effective at quick stopping and it kind of fishtailed making me fall down.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your rear tyres have worn out , replace them.

Note: Never apply only the rear brake , all bikes in the world tend to fishtail, unless you have ABS and I know your bike does not have it.

Even for a superbike its always advised to apply only the front brake since during brake due to load transfer to front wheel the rear wheel looses grip and fishtails more so if the tyre is worn.